# in add_summary for value in summary.value: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

This is a very basic tensorboard scalar log:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a = np.arange(10)
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype=tf.float32)
x_summ = tf.summary.scalar("X", x)
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/logdir')
writer.add_summary(x_summ)
```

However, I get an error in add_summary for value in summary.value:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'value'.
```

Any solution for this?

TensorFlow documentation says ValueError is raised when the summary tensor has a wrong shape or type. When I print `x_summ` it shows:

```
Tensor("X:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

I don't understand why is the shape `NULL` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value error is raised because you have to evaluate the summary node within a session.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    s = sess.run(x_summ)
    writer.add_summary(s)
```

But notice that this will raise another error, as you try to track 10 values in a scalar summary. But as I suppose that you will track some meaningful variable during training (like loss), this doesn't matter much.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, it works for variables with single value. So, I will have to loop across this array `a` to log every value individually in the summary. But when, I view this on TensorBoard, I get 10 different graphs with a single point. I did expect this, but how do I get one single graph with all 10 values in it.